# How do I detect scene changes in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere

I have a single clip with multiple edits in it. Is there an easy, automatic way to detect these? Ideally I'd just like them labelled in some way with support for "jump to the next label".

I realise it won't be 100% reliable since it would need to detect scene changes automatically, but perhaps there's something that can considerably speed up the process of splitting such a clip into separate scenes?

Comment: Could you elaborate a litte? Is your goal for Premiere to automatically detect environment change of a clip (for example from outfoors to indoors) and mark these spots for you?

Comment: @Speldosa I suppose anything along those lines would be very helpful, so I'll update the question a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't part of Premiere, but [Scenalyzer](http://www.scenalyzer.com) is an external tool for this that I've had some good luck with.  It can scan a large video file and split it into smaller ones based on frame change detection.  Then you can work with the smaller files much more easily.  There's a freeware version, and a more featured paid edition.

Comment: That website design doesn’t inspire confidence, hope it can do the job... Thanks!

Comment: It's hideous, yes, and the software is clunky too, but there's a free version and it worked pretty well.  I had a version from a few years ago and it met my needs.  Your needs may be different, and they may have screwed up a good thing since then.  One warning: there's a setting to delete source files when you're done splitting them.  DON'T DO THIS until and unless you trust the software.  I believe they call this kind of splitting "optical", as distinct from actually reading the timecode info.

Answer (score 1):

There is no automated way to analyse scene changes in Premiere.

> Ideally I'd just like them labelled in some way with support for
>   "jump to the next label".

I recommend you use [Markers](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/markers.html) in Premiere to manually mark scene changes. You can very quickly scan through the timeline and use the <kbd>M</kbd> key to add a Marker at the current position.

You can use <kbd>Shift + M</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + M</kbd> to iterate through each marker (forwards and backwards respectively). Use the Up and Down keys to find the start/end of each clip.

To make it easier to find scene changes, you can drag the divider on the top of the track to adjust the height and therefore get a better preview of the timeline.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've made a script which allows you to use the scene detection functionality of Davinci Resolve. Detect your scenes, make a new timeline of the resulting clips and export it as FCP7 V5 .xml, run the script on the .xml and you'll be able to import the converted .xml in Premiere! https://gumroad.com/products/CUnOP/